# Using [google-text-to-speech] v1Beta1 version in c#

Tags: google-text-to-speech

Does any one know how to use the V1Beta1 version in c#. It will be a great help if some one can point me to some example. Google has not created a Client for this version.

https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/text/synthesize#TimepointType

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (for Google.Apis.Texttospeech.v1) and could not find an example anywhere. I pieced it together from some Ruby Api docs, so, this works for me.

How to use Google.Apis.Texttospeech.v1 in C#:

```
var request = new Google.Apis.Texttospeech.v1.Data.SynthesizeSpeechRequest();
    
request.AudioConfig = new Google.Apis.Texttospeech.v1.Data.AudioConfig()
{
    AudioEncoding = "Linear16" // = WAV, or "MP3", "OGG_OPUS"
};

request.Input = new Google.Apis.Texttospeech.v1.Data.SynthesisInput
{
    Text = "Sample Speaker Text"  // Or use Ssml = "<speak> Your SSML Text. 
</speak>"
};

request.Voice = new Google.Apis.Texttospeech.v1.Data.VoiceSelectionParams
{
    LanguageCode = "en-EN",
    Name = "en-US-Wavenet-C"
};

var service = new Google.Apis.Texttospeech.v1.TexttospeechService(new 
Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer
    {
        ApplicationName = "My Sample App",
        ApiKey = "[Your API Key]"
    }
);

var response = service.Text.Synthesize(request).Execute();

using (var output = System.IO.File.Create("audioclip.wav"))
{
    var bytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(response.AudioContent);
    output.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```